# php function argument default value - how to know that def. value was applied?

Tags: php, function, default

I have a function

```
function my_func($id,$arg1='aaa',$arg2='bbb'){
 if($arg1=='aaa'){
     //means that def. value applied, real argument has not been provided
 }
 if($arg1=='bbb'){
     //means that def. value applied, real argument has not been provided
 }
}
```

I check if my values are default I will do one thing, if not - another thing.
But my user may call my function like

```
 my_func($id,'aaa','bbb')
```

So he provided real values. How I know that these values are real in my code, not default?

Comment: You are conflicting your question itself? according to first one what you gave in second code are def values not real argument. So please make your question more clear.

Comment: You can't. Use `NULL` as implied values, and set defaults yourself. The more important question is why you'd want to differentiate on identical values being supplied by the caller or the runtime.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I can't understand why my question is conflicting itself. I need to know when I have def values in my code and when user provided all arguments but with values identical to default. The issue is logic is different for def. and real values. And it's an issue if both of hem are identical.In other words, my_func(10000) and my_func(10000,'aaa','bbb') will do absolutely different things, but inside my_func it's no info were those values default or not. I hope it`s more clear now. Thanks

Comment: Don't worry, your question is not inconsistent. At least two of us here understand it...

Comment: Well, theoretically you could also use [`func_num_args()`](http://php.net/func_num_args), which returns the number of actually passed values (discounting defaults).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, when a user supplies the default value for an optional argument the result is *exactly* the same as when the argument is absent. There is no way to tell the difference.

What you *can* do is design your function so that the default values cannot be confused with actual, useful arguments. You can then detect this case and supply the values you *really* want used in this case. For example:

```
function my_func($id,$arg1=null,$arg2=null){
 if($arg1===null){
     $arg1 = "aaa";
     // do other default things
 }
 if($arg2===null){
     $arg2 = "bbb";
     // do other default things
 }
}
```

If the caller calls the function with `"aaa"`, it will not be mistaken for a default argument. Of course the caller can always call the function with `null` as the value, which will be indistinguishable from absent arguments; but that's not really such a bad thing, the special values just mean "do the default thing".

Comment: Thank you! Yes I thought about nulls but decided to figure it out with help of yours. In other words, we have a func check_pwd($site_id,$login='def_login',$passwd='def_pwd'). But what if login/pass will be ''def_login' and 'def_pwd' by chance? But provided solution above doesn't cover the situation when user need to provide null values. So in this case I think I need to consider special def values reserved in system. I thought that there sth like spec constant or function in php that may check was argument provided or not. As far as I can see, it doesn't exist. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea what you're trying to say in your comment!

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited it, it was saved not completely. Thanks

Comment: And btw, plase look at: $var1=null;$var2=null; my_func(10000,$var1,$var2) and my_func(10000) should still be different but if var1 and var2 were set to null somewhere in code, those 2 calls will be identical but they shouldn't be.

Comment: If `null` is a possible actual value for your parameters, just use a different default that is not a useful value; `-1`, `""` (empty string), `null`, `FALSE`, ...  I seriously doubt you have a task where negative integers, booleans, strings and `null` are all meaningful values.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I have a talk where var1 and var2 - login and password. yes login can`t be -1 or false, but it was just interesting to know how to avoid it more gracefully. Thank you for your help

Comment: "... those 2 calls will be identical but they shouldn't be." That's where you get it wrong: What matters is distinguishing real values from "do the default". Your code has no reason to care _how_ the caller spells "do the default". If `null` is an illegal value, all three cases are **and should be** equivalent.

Comment: I agree, but I am dealing with system where I have to fix 1k+ entries of function call. The function has def. values. And I was trying to distinguish def. from real values to save time. Thank you

Comment: There are over a thousand calls to a single function in your codebase? I feel for you-- the defaults are probably the least of your problems. I'll add one comment: I wouldn't worry about how the function is called, if it's called with default arguments it's asking for the default behavior. For username/password, I'd make the defaults be the empty string. That way you prevent empty passwords for free :-)

Comment: Ok thank you, actually it`s not my project, I`m just maintaining it. Thank you